# How can install sublime text on aarch64 architecture?

Tags: sublimetext3, arm64

I want to install sublime text on aarch64 architecture like Jetson TX2 Developer Kit. I am wondering how can I do this.
Thanks

Comment: Since it is only distributed as x86 and x86_64 binaries, the only way to run it on platforms other than these is with an x86 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Compile Atom for arm64 and that will be the best you can do, normally you should just use another system to write your code and then move it to the Jetson, what I do, I have an HDMI switcher and a USB hub switcher on the back of my monitor and connected to my PC and Jetson and then I write my code on the computer, commit it to Git and switch to the Jetson and done.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text now has an aarch64 (arm64) binary which is available from the product website.  Trying to use Atom on arm64 proved to be more trouble than it was worth in my experience.  As long as you are using a supported libc you should be able to run sublime out of the box.  Specifically, as in my case, musl is not supported; my solution has been to run it in a Debian OCI container (docker, podman, crun, etc).